# How to display a field in the Lead layout only when the field is not blank?

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, page-layout, isblank

In the lead object I need to display a custom text field on the lead page layout `ONLY IF` field is `NOT` blank.
 Is that feasible in Salesforce and how it can be achieved?

Comment: Are you using standard page layout or a VF page?

Comment: You can't do this with standard functionality, so it depends on if you're willing to write code or not.

Comment: I'm using a standard page layout.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using a standard page layout

You **cannot** dynamically show/hide field if you are using a standard page layout. Fields on standard page layout are static in nature and are displayed based on the FLS of the User.

If you opt for custom options by using VF page, you can do so by utilizing the `rendered` attribute on the applicable tags. E.g.,

```
<apex:outputField value="{!account.name}" rendered="your formula here"/>
```